# how to pass in the user-data when launching AWS instances using CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line-interface

I'm using the AWS CLI to launch instances, and the command is:
aws ec2 run-instances

what i'm expecting is to pass in a script as the user-data.
so, I did:
DATA=`base64 ./my_script`
on my Mac OSX, and then pass the DATA by:
aws ec2 run-instances --user-data $DATA

BUT, nothing happened after the instance launched

So, how exactly should I do?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is no need to base64 encode the data yourself.

You can prefix a file name/path with file://

So,

```
aws ec2 run-instances --user-data file://my_script
```

or

```
aws ec2 run-instances --user-data file:///full/path/to/my_script
```

Comment: It works for Linux(Ubuntu) but not for windows do we need some extra setting in windows

Comment: I don't have a Windows computer to test on. Consider opening a new question with complete details of what you are running and what results you are getting.

Answer (score 6):

To pass the script as a string, make sure to specify the interpreter as normal prior to your commands.  Hitting enter in the open string allows for adding a new line. Ex.:

```
$ aws ec2 run-instances --image-id ami-16d4986e --user-data '#!/bin/bash
> poweroff'
```