# Not able to run file passed to aws ec2 run-instances command

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli, user-data

The command that I used to create a new (ubuntu) instance is this:

```
aws ec2 run-instances --image-id ami-XXXXXXXX  --count 1 --instance-type 
t2.micro --key-name abcdef --query 'Instances[0].InstanceId' --user-data file:///Users/<username>/<somedir>/UserData.sh  --subnet-id subnet-XXXXXX --associate-public-ip-address
```

The UserData.sh contains this 3 lines including the newline:

```
#!/bin/bash

mkdir ~/latest
```

However, I do not see the "latest" dir when the system gets created and comes up. What am I doing wrong?

Disclaimer: I have already checked this: [how to pass in the user-data when launching AWS instances using CLI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22291755/how-to-pass-in-the-user-data-when-launching-aws-instances-using-cli#). as well as other forums.

Also, is there any way to know if there is any warning messages etc which can give me some insights into what I am doing wrong? Is there any permission necessary at a AWS level ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mkdir ~/latest
```

Whose home directory? **Specify absolute path** like `mkdir /home/myuser/latest`. Don't use C-Shell style notation.

Comment: @SuDu If this answer resolved your issue, please click the check mark the left of this answer to mark this question as resolved. This will signal to other SO users that this question has been resolved, and award you with a small amount of reputation.