# aws ec2 run-instances: script as the plain text is ignored

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to pass the script as the --user-data parameter.
If the same is run through `--user-data file://some_file.sh` all works. Also, it works if launch instance through AWS GUI by adding user-data in the correspondent launch configuration box.

My CLI command is

`aws ec2 run-instances --image-id ami-0cc0a36f626a4fdf5 --count 1 --instance-type t2.micro --key-name key_name --security-group-ids sg-00000000 --tag-specifications "ResourceType=instance,Tags=[{Key=Name,Value=some_name}]" --output table --user-data "sudo touch /tmp/install.log && sudo chmod 777 /tmp/install.log && echo $(date) >> /tmp/install.log"`

if the same run as a script, it's content formatted as below

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo touch /tmp/install.log
sudo chmod 777 /tmp/install.log
echo $(date) >> /tmp/install.log
```

Also, I'd like to mention that I tried to pass string in different formats like :

`--user-data echo "some text"`

`--user-data "command_1\n command_2\n"`

`--user-data "command_1 && command_2"`

`--user-data "command_1; command_2;"`

`--user-data "#!/bin/bash; command_1; command_2;"`

User-data after launch is seeing but not executed

`$ curl -L http://169.254.169.254/latest/user-data/`

Comment: nope. for test purpose, I only try just to create the file (and put inside its creation time)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first line must start with `#!`.

Then, subsequent lines are executed. They must be separated by a proper newline. It looks like `\n` is not interpreted correctly.

From [how to pass in the user-data when launching AWS instances using CLI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28331976/174777):

```
$ aws ec2 run-instances --image-id ami-16d4986e --user-data '#!/bin/bash
> poweroff'
```

As an experiment, I put this at the end of the `run-instances` command:

```
aws ec2 run-instances ... --user-data '#!
echo bar >/tmp/foo
'
```

When I logged into the instance, I could see the `/tmp/foo` file.

Comment: Yes, it really helped me. 
If I understood correctly, the importance here is to end the first open-quoted line ```'#!/bin/bash``` and then inside the command hit enter button and manually add one-by-one the next commands and finally close the ```--user-data``` string with ```'```.

My mistake was just copy-pasting pre-formatted run-command where new lines of the script were not interpreted by AWS CLI correctly.

Thank you so much and Happy coming New Year!

Comment: You can also put the script in a file and reference it with: `--user-data file://my_script.txt.`